# Cannot put more than 1 group of symbols to Elastic search regex query

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have an index `destinations` with documents that have `json` field. It's a string with valid JSON.

The index does contain the document with `json`: `{"to": { "issGuid": null }}`

When I execute:

```
GET destinations/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"regexp": {"json": ".*null.*"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

the target document is found. But when I run:

```
GET destinations/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"regexp": {"json": ".*to.*null.*"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I see no results.

I checked regex several times with online tools - it matches the target document `json` field. I tried both: Kibana Dev Tools tab and direct curl to Elasticsearch host. Results are the same.

For sure I want to make regex even more complicated to find all documents with null values inside `to` of `json` field. But it's the next step and for now will be really happy to get any help here.

Thanks!